# Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova : Error when creating or opening Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am running Visual Studio 2015 under Windows 10.

I was able to successfully create and open Cordova projects, but suddenly one day I started receiving the following error message:

> An equivalent project (a project with the same global properties and tools version) is already present in the project collection, with the path "{path-to-cordova-project}". To load an equivalent into this project collection, unload this project first.

When I go to modify the Visual Studio installation, I can see "HTML/JavaScript (Apache Cordova)" appearing twice in the list of features:
[image]

As you can see, there is a replaced version, and an Update 1.
I have tried every combination of uninstalling/installing each of Apache Cordova (Replaced) and (Update 1), and also Tools and Windows SDK 10.0.10240. I also tried deselecting/selecting to reinstall.

I managed to get it working once for creating new projects, but when I opened a project which failed to open before, it started failing again for creation and opening, and haven't been able to get it working again.

I tried completely uninstalling VS 3 times, once using the command G:\vs_professional.exe /uninstall /force
I also tried tried renaming C:\ProgramData\Package Cache folder before installing again.
But it seems to be leaving bytes somewhere, because after reinstalling I can still see the Recent projects, and project templates downloaded before uninstalling.

I am now going to consider formatting the partition and reinstall Windows, but this is very frustrating and disappointing.

I hope someone come up with a solution for this before I proceed to format.
Thanks.

PS: I think the latest thing I installed before this started to happen was ASP.NET 5 Beta 7. But I am not sure if this was the root cause of this problem.

Comment: Its almost certainly something to do with ASP.NET 5 Beta 7 as I installed it yesterday, and am now getting the same issue. Very frustrating as I want to use vnext for my api and cordova for my client :(

Comment: Thank you for reporting this issue. We worked with the ASP.net team to provide two fixes, one that will ship with the next Cordova update and another that will ship with the next ASP.net beta. Please keep your eye on the notification center to see the update when it is released.

Comment: @MichaelBraude I've tried the method below and I can't get it fixed. Any possibility for a manual work around? Can you tell me what files need to be deleted?

Comment: @JonZ We are shipping an update to the Cordova tools today (10/6/15) which fixes the issue. There is no manual workaround. Please keep an eye on the notification center to see when the update is available.

Comment: @MichaelBraude Thanks... I ended up doing a forced uninstall then deleted the visual studio folder to fix it.. It will be nice to have  a real fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem with (Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova Update 1 + ASP.NET 5 beta 7). I resolved it by uninstalling beta 7 of ASP.NET 5 (uninstall explain [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48738)) and do a devenv.exe /resetuserdata

Comment: I was able to fix this with: devenv /resetuserdata.
Now I have Apache Cordova Tools (Update 2) working with ASP.NET 5 Beta 7

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it uninstalling apache cordova tools and using the vs installer to install it again.

Also did removed `AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache` and `devenev /resetuserdata`

so that may be also needed, not sure.